# DNS Named.service isc_stdio_open 'data/named.run' failed: permission denied

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, centos7, systemd, dns-hosting

Hi guys I have problems with starting systemctl named.service 
I was trying to install bind & configure everything to make a public domain name work but I ran in this problem.

```
systemctl status named.service
```

and I get this error

```
    ● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-05-07 07:08:12 EDT; 21min ago
  Process: 29283 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 29280 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z /etc/named.conf; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1228 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net named[29285]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net named[29285]: command channel listening on ::1#953
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net named[29285]: isc_stdio_open 'data/named.run' failed: permission denied
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net named[29285]: configuring logging: permission denied
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net named[29285]: loading configuration: permission denied
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net named[29285]: exiting (due to fatal error)
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
May 07 07:08:12 darksys.net systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```

Is there something wrong with the permissions?

Also SELinux status

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable assumption, especially with selinux off. Have you changed the working directory or changed the permissions? (Out of the box it ought to start just fine with the normal rhel/centos packages)

Comment: which user ran `systemctl start named.service` ?

Comment: a user of the wheel group with sudo rights, not root.

Comment: I also did not change any permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a directory under chroot

```
cd /var/named
mkdir chroot/var/named/data
chown named:named  chroot/var/named/data
```

and after that

```
sudo systemctl start named.service
```

I checked it with

```
systemctl status named.service
```

and everything was up and running.